# How to weave using AspectJ 1.7 and Maven 3.3?

Tags: maven, aspectj

I have been looking tirelessly for a working example of a simple application that uses AspjectJ 1.7 and is compiled using Maven 3.3. I have been able to find complex examples that use older versions of AsjectJ and older versions of Maven, but nothing recent.

Any related example that somebody could be able to provide would be incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

See my simple example of of `java.lang.instrument` and AspectJ Weaver on github?

https://github.com/noahlz/weaver-demo

Comment: Unfortunately your example is using Maven 2 and AspectJ 1.6.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do those specific versions make a difference?  Can't you adapt / upgrade my example to your needs?

Comment: I am in the process of creating corporate reference documents for developers who are migrating from using Ant to Maven and we are tied to using the specific versions, it is out of my control...But this has been  very painful as I am not a developer and have been doing my best to understand what the purpose of weaving is and how it works...